# Dynamic CSS editing in Vaadin 7

Tags: java, css, gwt, web-applications, vaadin

I want to edit the css of an embedded image dynamically and using push, the intention is to build a web browser game and I don't want a 'tool explosion', I'm using Hibernate+JPA, Vaadin, ivy and a tool for server-push.

I don't want to use GWT, partly because the only part of it that I want is the canvas drawing, which seems to be really overkill, GWT is massive and I don't want to learn it at this stage simply so I can draw 2D pictures and move them around smoothly.

Here's how I'm loading an image.

```
Embedded embedded_1;

....

embedded_1.setSource(new FileResource(
new File(VaadinService.getCurrent().getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
+"/WEB-INF/images/sun.gif")));

....

mainLayout = new AbsoluteLayout();
mainLayout.addComponent(embedded_1, "top:0.0px;left:0.0px:");
```

Inside Absolute layout there's a field I want to access.

```
LinkedHashMap<Component, ComponentPosition>  componentToCoordinates ...
```

I looked at the other methods that get called when I do

```
 mainLayout.addComponent(embedded_1, "top:0.0px;left:0.0px:");
```

and they don't do anything special, (ie access non-java files or use any dynamically generated code), there's a method that cleans up and validates the CSS, its wrapped into a **ComponentPosition** object and then it is put unceremoniously into the HashMap.

Why can't I access this HashMap and do edits on the values already mapped by a key without changing the key itself. I want to take an embedded object and change it's css position dynamically, to do that all I would need to do is execute code

```
componentToCoordinates.get(reference).setString("top:10.0px;left:0.0px;");
```

and I could generate the string dynamically etc.

Is there a 'proper' way of doing this or is it something I have to create my own solution for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for though it wasn't in the form I expected.

There's a method in the layout API called getPosition(Component c) that will return the css string.

You can then change the string and put it back into the Map using setPosition(Component c ComponentPosition cp)